# How to make Facebook mention like highlighting word in UITextView?

Tags: ios, objective-c, facebook

HERE IS SAMPLE IMAGE -->

[image]

I'm trying to make text input feature very similar to Facebook's one. The mention that start with @ will generate list of my friends name then selecting one will act as something like an object. So deleting the highlighted word will remove whole word in UITextView.

I wonder if that is part of UITextView. Does anyone know how to implement?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 2):

I know this is a pretty old question but I've actually made libraries that assist with mentions, when to show the list, does the highlighting etc.  It uses attributes on an attributed string to set background.

- https://github.com/szweier/SZMentions
- https://github.com/szweier/SZMentionsSwift

Comment: hi steve. looks like a cool pod. Have you some example code for tagging facebook friends?

Comment: The library simply allows you to be notified when @ is typed and allow you to display a list to choose from.  It also helps manage the list of mentions added to the textview.  As for specifically tagging Facebook friends that would require digging into the Facebook api and connect it within your app.  I don't have an example for that.  There is a sample app that runs if you pull the swift library that you can run though.

Comment: Thanks! I will give it a try, maybe making a own pod out of it.

Answer (score 0):

You'll want to have a look at [NSAttributedString](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#DOCUMENTATION/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSAttributedString_Class/Reference/Reference.html). While this class exists in iOS 3.2 or greater, you cannot display it in a UITextView unless you are on iOS 6 or later.